# problemas con base de datos en cpanel

Tags: cpanel

hola grupo tengo un problema con la base de datos en el hosting CPANEL tengo un proyecto echo en laravel y al importar la base de datos en cpanel no me carga mis vistas como vistas sino como tablas vacías y cuando creo manual mente mis vistas si carga la informacion en las vistas de las otras tablas pero ya corriendo el sistema me sale el siguiente error [image: este es el error]

y lo mas raro es q cuando corro el sistema localmente no hay ningun problema

este error q indico solo es con las vistas de mi base de datos en cpanel luego informacion de otras tablas es visualizada en el sistema

Comment: El problema está en cómo estás cargando tus vistas. Es posible que ese proceso las esté definiendo como tablas

Comment: cpanel es un administrador general de sitios web. No tiene nada que ver con tu base de datos. Supongo que tu base de datos sera mysql? como cargas las vistas en tu base de datos? como las creaste?

Comment: las cree con create view (nombre de la vista) en base de datos local mysql tengo 4 vistas y cuando realizo la importacion de esa base de datos en cpanel solo me importa dos vistas pero las importa como tablas y no tiene nada de contenido, ahora ya q no me carga bien las vistas en cpanel yo las creo de nuevo en cpanel desde la consola estas se crean y tb se llenan con informacion de las de mas tablas pero al momento de correr el sistema me sale ese error q mostre en la imagen de mi publicacion o como es que tengo q crear vistas en el phpmyadmin de cpanel y yo este cometiendo un error